# Nested Query - Two Level Filtering

Tags: mysql, sql

### Schema

- Researcher(ID (PK), )
- Activity (PID (publication_FK, PK) , RID (researcher_FK , PK))
- Publication (ID (PK) , Year)

`PID` , `RID` in `Activity` form its composite PK and each correspond to the FK of the `Publication` and `Researcher` tables, respectively

### Query

For each researcher, who was has at least 2 publications, retrieve all their publications since the year 2000

### Attempt

```sql
SELECT PID, RID
FROM Activity
WHERE RID IN (SELECT  RID
  FROM Activity
  GROUP BY RID
  HAVING COUNT(RID) >= 2)
```

How do I filter this interim result by Publication Year?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join to `publications`.  Using your approach:

```
SELECT a.PID, a.RID
FROM Activity a JOIN
     Publications p
     ON p.ID = a.PID
WHERE p.year >= 2000 AND
      a.RID IN (SELECT a2.RID
                FROM Activity a2
                GROUP BY a2.RID
                HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
               ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it filters all publications records on the year , or is the nested query returned first and then joined with publication and the results filtered?

Comment: @Scb . . . The references are separate, so the filtering is only in the outer query.